# How set ticks x axis with datetime on ggplot

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2, line-plot

I'm plotting a dataset a little over three months long with a data each half hour.
So in my dataframe I have a datetime vector with the format `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS` - year, month, day, hour, minute, second.
I want just to set the ticks on the x-axis each fiveteen days.
I tried with `scale_x_date` and `scale_x_datetime` setting the `breaks`, but without result and an error message.
I didn't understand well the difference between `scale_x_date`, `scale_x_datetime`, but I think that in my case, with a datetime vector I should use `scale_x_datetime`.

It's very diffcult share my dataset, because is very large and using a smaller portion I thing wouldn't give enough material to figure out my problem.

So I share the code that I used and the graphical output that I have.

```r
library(ggplot2) 

ggplot(fluxmxrdesp,aes(x=Datetime))+
  geom_line(aes(y=mz31_mxr,colour="Formaldehyde"), size = 1)+
  labs(y = "VMR (ppb)" , x = "Date",colour="Legend")+
  scale_colour_manual(name='',values = ("Formaldehyde"="darkolivegreen4"))+
  theme_classic()+theme(legend.position = "top") + 
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(r=25),color="black", size=18),
        axis.text.y = element_text(color="black",size=14),
        axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(t=10),color="black", size=18),
        axis.text.x = element_text(color="black", size=14),
        legend.text = element_text(color = "black", size = 18))
```

Short dataset

```
structure(list(Datetime = structure(c(1527813000, 1527814800, 
1527816600, 1527818400, 1527820200, 1527822000), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"), H = c(-6.088316625, 
-9.882886968, -6.533935906, -5.305478189, -3.844176459, -12.90132526
), LE = c(0.946172041403071, -1.10377384331459, -1.53126820765533, 
-2.28713506105331, 1.59264111550727, -1.08866725213062), Turbulence = c(0.0838, 
0.128583643, 0.0806, 0.0875, 0.0733, 0.168911167), Wind_dir = c(255.3307133, 
277.4016533, 281.2972942, 274.410293, 241.1132665, 256.6879056
), mz31_flux = c(0.00754, 0.0393, -0.00867, -0.0075, -0.00622, 
0.0347), mz33_flux = c(-0.0898, 0.162, -0.0944, 0.0466, 0.0614, 
-0.271), mz39_flux = c(0.131, -0.245, -0.157, 0.153, 0.147, 0.322
), mz42_flux = c(-0.00644, 0.00684, 0.0103, 0.0135, -0.0039, 
0.017), mz45_flux = c(0.0245, 0.107, 0.031, 0.025, -0.0294, -0.0719
), mz47_flux = c(-0.031, -0.061, -0.0345, 0.0482, -0.0244, 0.0803
), mz59_flux = c(0.0309, 0.0639, 0.0345, 0.0424, 0.0231, -0.0926
), mz61_flux = c(-0.013, -0.0187, -0.0155, 0.0382, 0.00854, 0.053
), mz69_flux = c(0.0208, 0.0213, -0.00855, 0.011, -0.0112, -0.0213
), mz71_flux = c(0.00807, -0.00698, 0.00235, 0.00435, -0.00648, 
0.0109), mz75_flux = c(-1.83e-17, -0.00405, -0.000647, 0.000867, 
-0.000523, 0.0108), mz79_flux = c(-0.00999, 0.03, 0.00945, 0.00893, 
0.0136, -0.028), mz85_flux = c(0.00681, -0.0219, 0.00518, -0.0091, 
-0.00905, -0.0183), mz87_flux = c(0.00908, 0.0112, 0.00519, 0.00973, 
0.00647, -0.0135), mz93_flux = c(-0.0299, 0.0532, 0.0417, 0.0203, 
-0.0189, 0.0637), mz99_flux = c(-0.00727, 0.00771, 0.00569, -0.0047, 
-0.00118, -0.00661), mz101_flux = c(0.00489, 0.0114, 0.00326, 
-0.00676, 0.0051, 0.0165), mz107_flux = c(-0.0279, -0.0268, 0.0211, 
0.0167, -0.0084, 0.0372), mz111_flux = c(-0.00163, 0.00664, -0.00186, 
0.00456, 0.00155, 0.00682), mz113_flux = c(-0.0013, 0.0056, 0.000907, 
0.00154, -0.00125, 0.00679), mz135_flux = c(-0.00619, -0.00983, 
0.00429, 0.00534, 0.00503, 0.0231), mz137_flux = c(0.0233, 0.0346, 
0.0171, -0.000554, 0.0282, -0.0985), mz149_flux = c(-0.00176, 
-0.00336, 0.000902, -0.000605, -0.000848, 0.00901), mz155_flux = c(0.00116, 
-0.00137, 0.000528, 0.000541, -5.79e-05, -7.08e-05), mz31_mxr = c(7.27e-06, 
0.000172, 7.29e-06, 7.69e-06, 6.69e-06, 0.000154), mz33_mxr = c(0.0042, 
0.00439, 0.00349, 0.00321, 0.00334, 0.00323), mz39_mxr = c(0.0038, 
0.0038, 0.00364, 0.00352, 0.0033, 0.00323), mz42_mxr = c(0.000102, 
0.000135, 7.58e-05, 0.000112, 9.04e-05, 0.000143), mz45_mxr = c(0.00128, 
0.0012, 0.00107, 0.001, 0.00101, 0.00099), mz47_mxr = c(0.000273, 
0.000476, 0.000236, 0.000398, 0.000264, 0.000476), mz59_mxr = c(0.00205, 
0.00194, 0.00193, 0.0019, 0.00182, 0.00172), mz61_mxr = c(3.78e-05, 
0.000182, 0.000124, 0.000261, 0.000156, 0.000241), mz69_mxr = c(0.000299, 
0.000313, 0.000291, 0.000255, 0.00026, 0.000252), mz71_mxr = c(7.59e-05, 
6.53e-05, 6.75e-05, 6.59e-05, 6.21e-05, 6.33e-05), mz75_mxr = c(2.21e-21, 
1.42e-05, 1.89e-07, 3.56e-07, 3.07e-07, 2.16e-05), mz79_mxr = c(0.000346, 
0.000406, 0.000382, 0.00031, 0.000383, 0.000293), mz85_mxr = c(0.000151, 
0.00014, 0.000143, 0.000133, 0.000123, 0.000111), mz87_mxr = c(9.9e-05, 
9.82e-05, 9.68e-05, 8.91e-05, 8.39e-05, 8.74e-05), mz93_mxr = c(0.00228, 
0.00268, 0.00252, 0.00208, 0.0024, 0.00189), mz99_mxr = c(3.69e-05, 
6.19e-05, 3.81e-05, 5.54e-05, 1.45e-05, 4.66e-05), mz101_mxr = c(0.000155, 
0.000155, 0.000157, 0.000147, 0.000137, 0.000139), mz107_mxr = c(0.00129, 
0.00152, 0.00142, 0.00115, 0.00133, 0.00104), mz111_mxr = c(1.09e-05, 
5.27e-05, 9.35e-06, 5.86e-06, 6.03e-06, 3.74e-05), mz113_mxr = c(2.15e-05, 
3.78e-05, 2.07e-05, 2e-05, 1.89e-05, 3.51e-05), mz135_mxr = c(0.000153, 
0.000141, 0.000115, 9.73e-05, 9.94e-05, 8.94e-05), mz137_mxr = c(0.000142, 
0.000122, 4.16e-05, 1.78e-06, 7.94e-05, 0.000197), mz149_mxr = c(1.58e-06, 
2.22e-05, 1.13e-06, 6.74e-07, 9.28e-07, 1.84e-05), mz155_mxr = c(1.57e-06, 
4.71e-06, 3.58e-07, 4.42e-07, 4.64e-08, 4.9e-08)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

As you can see in the figure ([here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1sjh.png)) the tick, as text, for each month.
I'd like to have something like: `01/06/2018 00:00, 15/06/2018 00:00, 1/07/2018 00:00` and so on.
Also with the possibility of reducing the window between one tick and another

Comment: Please share the input data by adding the output of `dput(fluxmxrdesp)` to your question, or `dput(head(fluxmxrdesp))` if your data is too big

Comment: `scale_x_datetime( date_breaks = "15 day")` should work.  Without seeing what you tried or the error message this is just a guess.

Comment: @IceCreamToucan. I add a sub-daset.

Comment: @DaveT I tried.
It works, but it put ticks on day 10 and 25, Instead I prefer day 1 and 15, 1 and 15 for the next month, and so on.
Then, it doesn't put the time. I wish to see 00:00.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want to specify the dates to just the 1st and 15th, you have to manually create the vector of breaks and then use this vector inside the scale_x_datetime function.
In this case I manually created the date range from June 1 to October 15.

```
#create breaks for the 1st and 15th
breaks1st<-seq.Date(as.Date("2018-06-01"), as.Date("2018-10-01"), by="month")
breaks15th<-seq.Date(as.Date("2018-06-15"), as.Date("2018-10-15"), by="month")
mybreaks<-sort(c(breaks1st, breaks15th))
mybreaks<-as.POSIXct(mybreaks, tz="GMT")

ggplot(fluxmxrdesp, aes(x=Datetime))+
  geom_line(aes(y=mz31_mxr,colour="Formaldehyde"), size = 1)+
  labs(y = "VMR (ppb)" , x = "Date",colour="Legend")+
  scale_colour_manual(name='',values = ("Formaldehyde"="darkolivegreen4"))+
  theme_classic()+theme(legend.position = "top") + 
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(r=25),color="black", size=18),
        axis.text.y = element_text(color="black",size=14),
        axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(t=10),color="black", size=18),
        axis.text.x = element_text(color="black", size=14, angle=30, hjust = 1)),
        legend.text = element_text(color = "black", size = 18)) +
  scale_x_datetime(breaks=mybreaks, date_labels="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
```

In order to have the labels fit, I needed to angle the label text.
I would recommend not adding the "%H:%M" to the labels as the time component does not provide any additional significance and adds a considerable amount of clutter to the axis.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It works as I wish.
Thank you also for your advice.
I think that yes, it's better to avoid hours and minutes lab.

Comment: Yes I know. I've accepted it. Maybe I clicked on again for error.